# Получение данных из xml Unity

Tags: c#, xml, unity3d

Привет всем. Имею xml файл такого формата:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <locations>
        <location id="1">
            <level name="3" complete="True" stars="2" firstMisson="True" secondMission="False" thridMission="False" />
        </location>
        <location id="2">
           <level name="4" complete="True" stars="3" firstMisson="True" secondMission="True" thridMission="True" />
        </location>
    </locations>
```

Подскажите как получить данные которые в дальнейшем использовать.

ну вроде с первым пунктом разобрался.

Создал классы из xml

```
    [System.Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "level")]
    public class Level
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "complete")]
        public string Complete { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "stars")]
        public string Stars { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "firstMisson")]
        public string FirstMisson { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "secondMission")]
        public string SecondMission { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "thridMission")]
        public string ThridMission { get; set; }
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "location")]
    public class Location
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "level")]
        public Level Level { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "locations")]
    public class Locations
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "location")]
        public Location Location { get; set; }

        public List<Locations> LocDb = new List<Locations>();
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "xml")]
    public class Xml
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "locations")]
        public Locations Locations { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот метод для десериализаци

```
     public List<Locations> locDB = new List<Locations>();

     public static void LoadData()
        {
            string filepath = Application.dataPath + @"/XML/GameXMLdata.xml";

            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(locDB.GetType());
            var stream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open);


            locDB = (List<Locations>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stream); // На эту строку ругается
            //<locations xmlns=''> was not expected

            stream.Close();

            Debug.Log(locDB[1].Location.Id);

         }
```

Хочу данные загнать в list с которого и тягать их. Подскажите в чём косяк. Как лучше запилить чтобы легче тягать было.

Comment: Вам нужно почитать о разных методах и способах чтения XML в языке c#. Ибо их достаточно много и разных, чтоб их все описывать

Comment: Как вариант можно использовать XML сериализацию. Для этого создаются объекты описывающие структуру ваших данных и через нее загоняем в XML данные. В понедельник с работы скину вариант как делал. В итоге получается очень быстро сохранение, загрузка и работаешь с данными как с объектами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать десериализацию.

В этом вам поможет  `System.Xml.Serialization` и конкретно `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`, необходимо привести некоторые подготовительные работы.

Для этого приводите свой xml файл к такому виду(в дальнейшем можете вернуть обратно все параметры и их значения убранные из открывающего тега):

```
<xml>
<locations>
    <location id="1">
        <level name="3" complete="True" stars="2" firstMisson="True" secondMission="False" thridMission="False" />
    </location>
    <location id="2">
       <level name="4" complete="True" stars="3" firstMisson="True" secondMission="True" thridMission="True" />
    </location>
</locations>
</xml>
```

Затем копируете это содержимое в буфер обмена. В visual studio есть очень удобная фишка, про которую почему то не многие знают. При работе с json или xml нет нужды создавать класс для сериализации вручную. Вам необходимо создать новый файл класса и удалить из него абсолютно все строки, далее нужно всего лишь перейти по пути:

```
Правка(Edit) => Специальная вставка(special paste) => Вставить XML как классы(Paste XML as classes)
```

И класс для работы с этой XML будет создан автоматически.

Далее вы десериализуете свою XML и работаете уже с объектом.

Более детально можно ознакомиться вот здесь:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

Как было сказано в комментарии решений может быть действительно множество. На мой взгляд это одно из удобных.

Answer (score 1):

**Способ 1:**

Сделать все ручками, используя [LINQ TO XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq(v=vs.110).aspx) и получить необходимые данные, которые затем загрузить в переменные. Используя пространство имён `System.Xml.Linq`.

**Способ 2:**

Через вложенные циклы обойти узлы XML и записать данные в переменные. Используя [пространство имён](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml(v=vs.110).aspx) `System.Xml`.

[Руководство по XML на русском языке.](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.1.php)

**Способ 3:**

Создается класс на основании XML. При загрузке XML выполняется десерилизация к типу класса и .NET автоматически все распарсит и вернет заполненный объект.

[Руководство по сериализации/десериализации на русском языке.](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.4.php)